# Why I can't exit the Fullscreen using esitFullscreen method?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullscreen

Whenever I try to exit the Fullscreen in the console it shows that **exitFullscreen is not a function**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="o()">O</button>
  <button onclick="x()">X</button>
  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function o(){
   document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
  }
   function x(){
   document.documentElement.exitFullscreen();
   }
  
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

From the code above by clicking on button x I should exit Fullscreen but it is not happening

Comment: To exit full screen it's document.exitFullScreen(). You don't select an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

`requestFullscreen` is a method on **elements**

`exitFullscreen` is a method on the **`document`**

Answer (score 1):

use this  for exit the full screen

```
document.exitFullscreen();
```